# C# having trouble binding end point for ebay

Tags: c#, websocket, ebay-api

I'm getting the following exception thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' in
>   mscorlib.dll The content type text/xml of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related;
>   type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that
>   the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first
>   330 bytes of the response were: '2018-01-22
>   04:53:02`2`RequestError1SeriousError00'

I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here is the system service model from my web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BulkDataExchangeService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
                    maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport"> 
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/> 
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BulkDataExchangeService"
            contract="BulkDataExchangeServicePort" name="BulkDataExchangeService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="machine\user" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

THis is the code I'm using to try and create the upload job:

```
private void CreateUploadJobEbay()
    {
        var ebayAuthTokenSetting = _settingService.GetSettingByKey(
                            "ebaysetting.authtoken", "");

        //EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://webservices.sandbox.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService");

        BulkDataExchangeServicePortClient client = new BulkDataExchangeServicePortClient("BulkDataExchangeService");

        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);

            //Add the request headers

            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN", ebayAuthTokenSetting);
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "BulkDataExchangeService");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.0.0");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "SOAP12");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "createUploadJob");


            //Create the request
            CreateUploadJobRequest req = new CreateUploadJobRequest();

            //Supply additional parameters

            //The UUID must be unique. Once used, you can't use it again
            req.UUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            //Specify job type

            req.uploadJobType = "ReviseInventoryStatus";

            req.fileType = FileType.XML;

            req.fileTypeSpecified = true;

            //Get the response


            CreateUploadJobResponse resp = client.createUploadJob(req);
            Debug.WriteLine("code is hitting here >>> ");
            Debug.WriteLine("resp = " + resp);
            Debug.WriteLine("code is hitting here >>> ");
        }
    }
```

This is the part where the exception gets thrown `CreateUploadJobResponse resp = client.createUploadJob(req);`

UPDATE:
the bulk data exchange service code can be [found here](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1335) It's near the bottom in the BDXSample.zip file

Anyone know how to resolve this. Cheers

Comment: What other FileType values are there? Have you tried without setting the req.fileType?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I tried to remove the file type but still same problem, also see my update at b ottom of question, I added like to bulkdataexchangeservice

Answer (score 0):

Should you use `BulkDataExchangeServicePortClient("BulkDataExchangeServiceSOAP")`  instead?  (ending with SOAP whereas your code omitted that part)

Also I did not see `req.fileTypeSpecified = true;`  in the linked page. Maybe you don't need that line.

Comment: Hi Anthony McGrath I tried what you suggested but still had problem. I think it may be to do with running from my local machine and sending http > https
I'm going to try using JSON API instead as the LMS API seems way too clunky